# Insert array in collection after specific index in laravel

Tags: laravel, collections

i want to insert the item (array) after specific index in the laravel collection. i am using this code:

```
 foreach ($posts as $key => $post) {
      foreach ($friendsArray as $date => $friend) {
        if ($post->updated_at->format('Y-m-d') == $date) {
            $posts->push($friend);
            $friendsArray->forget($date);
        }
      }
   }

   dd($posts);
```

Result is as Below:

```
#items: array:9 [▼
      0 => Post {#862 ▶}
      1 => Post {#863 ▶}
      2 => Post {#864 ▶}
      3 => Post {#865 ▶}
      4 => Post {#866 ▶}
      5 => Post {#867 ▶}
      6 => Post {#868 ▶}
      7 => Post {#869 ▶}
      8 => Collection {#956 ▶}
    ]
```

Problem is the collection help Push insert the value in the last but I want to insert after a specific Index. For example i want to isert it after 2nd array .

Thanks in advance

Comment: if you want to insert by any condtion check simple check the condition and put it in another array and then insert that whole array.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `splice(int $offset, int|null $length = null, mixed $replacement = [])` method.

Example:

```
// $offset as the postition
// 0 because you don't want to remove any items
// $friend as replacement
$posts->splice($offset, 0, $friend);
```

See [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-splice).

Comment: I am happy to help. Could you mark this as the answer so others can see it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
foreach ($posts as $key => $post) {
      foreach ($friendsArray as $date => $friend) {
        if ($post->updated_at->format('Y-m-d') == $date) {
            $post->friend = $friend;
        }
      }
   }

   dd($posts);
```

Comment: first remove 2nd foreach and then test it by passing and testing array to friend...

Comment: first remove 2nd foreach and then test it.

Comment: Please provide a working solution. Answeres are not supposed to include guesses

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.